# Shared Exchange Calendar View

Tags: exchange, calendar

My department creates a shared calendar for everyone to enter their out-of-office times. This requires duplicate entry for those of us who keep all our info in our own Exchange calendar.

Is there a way in Exchange to create a View that's simply a combination view of multiple users' calendars?

For example, we would create a view with all the departments' users calendars combined, but only those marked "out of office". Ideally, the subject line would also include the user's name, but this would not be 100% necessary.

Answer (score 2):

There's a way to do it in Outlook and has been for years. When users click on their Calendar, they get a new button on the toolbar called "View Group Schedules." Then, they can make groups of users that they care about and view their free/busy times, and if they have reviewer or better rights, they can see details.

If someone is handy with programming, you can also scrape the free/busy and make a webpage out of it - I'm sure there's a handful of free programs/scripts out there to do exactly that.

Comment: Right. But no way to do this in Exchange, creating a shared view, right?

Comment: For what you're asking, no. There are Public Folders which can contain calendars, although I believe I've read that those are being deprecated in recent Exchange versions, you don't say what version you have. But the users would still have to make double manual entries.

Or you can just train your users on an existing feature, as I suggested :-)